# jQuery mobile can't properly autodivide data

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm trying to create an IOS app with PhoneGap and jQuery mobile.
The target is to receive news data (json) from a web service and display it.
It's all working except for the autodivider function of jquery mobile.

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).on("pageinit", "#news", function(){
    $("#newsContainer ul").listview({
        autodividers: true,
        autodividersSelector: function (li) {
            var out = li.attr("category");
            return out;
        }
    }).listview("refresh");

    getNews(15);

    function getNews(count){
        $.ajax({
            url: '*someURL*/file.php?count='+count,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data, status){

                    $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                        $('#newsContainer ul').append('<li category="'+item.category+'"><a>'+item.image+'<div style="float:left;white-space:normal;">'+item.headline+'</div><div style="float:left">'+item.content+'</div></div style="clear:both"></div></a></li>').listview('refresh');
                    });

                $('#newsContainer ul').listview('refresh');

            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('Fehler bei JSON Verarbeitung');
                $('#newsContainer ul').append('<li>Es ist ein Fehler beim Laden der News aufgetreten</li>').listview('refresh');
            }
        });

    }

});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="news">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>News</h1> 
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="newsContainer">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-corners="false" data-inset="false" data-theme="a" data-dividertheme="a" data-filter="true" data-sort="true" data-autodividers="true">
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar ui-block-a" data-position="fixed" data-id="myFooter">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#news" data-iconpos="top" data-icon="home">News </a> </li>
                <li><a href="#site2" data-iconpos="top" data-icon="home">Seite2 </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't merge all the equal values together.
I attached an image to better demonstrate the issue.

[image: jquery Mobile autodivider Issue]

Comment: first of all, why are using `pageinit` and `ready`? `ready` shouldn't be used with jQuery Mobile. Remove `ready` and use proper [jQuery Mobile events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/). And refresh listview after you finish appending items (once the loop ends). `$('#newsContainer').listview('refresh');`

Comment: I wasn't aware of the special jQuery mobile events. I inserted everything inside `pageinit` now and added the refresh right after the loop but it didn't change anything...

Comment: replace `pageinit` with `pagebeforeshow`, try it. and here `$("#newsContainer ul").listview({` remove `ul`

Comment: that doesn't work, neither.

Comment: third line in your code `$("#newsContainer ul").listview({` remove `ul`.

Comment: when I remove `ul`it doesn't work at all.

Comment: sorry my bad, i just realized this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32338/discussion-between-omar-and-damian-frizzi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this link:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/autodivider-features-group-count

Replacing the code did work for me.

Seems like jquery mobile doesn't support grouping items with the same value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that the question is old, but since no one have provided a sufficient solution - here's my attempt.

The listview widget doesn't sort the li-elements for you, you need to do that yourself.

You can easily do this by using the tsort-plugin: http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

```
var thisView = $('.listview');
$('li',thisView).tsort();
thisView.listview().listview('refresh');
```